# Databind is not showing data

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous, mvvm

I am trying to make a wpf application using MongoDB as the database. I am using the MVVM and in the view model they have the following constructor:

```
public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
    _dataService.GetData(
        (item, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                // Report error here
                return;
            }
            _items = item.ToList();
        });
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is trying to databind `_items` to my datatable. I see the wpf application open up but I have an empty table and `_items` above is empty. The following is the interface `IDataService`:

```
namespace ComplexDemo.Model
{
   public interface IDataService
   {
      Task GetData(Action<DataItem [], Exception> callback);
   }
}
```

and my `idataservice.GetData` function:

```
public async Task GetData(Action<DataItem [], Exception> callback)
{
    List<DataItem> items = new List<DataItem>();
    // Use this to connect to the actual data service
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");

    var list = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
    foreach(var doc in list)
    {
        var data = new DataItem
        {
            Id = doc.GetElement("_id").Value.AsObjectId.ToString(),
            Name = doc.GetElement("Name").Value.AsString,
            City = doc.GetElement("City").Value.AsString,
            State = doc.GetElement("State").Value.AsString
        };
        items.Add(data);
    }

    callback(items.ToArray(), null);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "not" instead of "now"?

Comment: I meant not thanks and I did change the heading.

Comment: do you get any data from you database? I.e. what is the content of `var list`? Do you get any errors, exceptions, ...?

Comment: @derpirscher, Yes. I have checked the GetData function and I am getting the right data from the database. When it leaves the function and comes back, the count goes from 5(what it should be) to 0.

Comment: @barakisbrown If I understand you correctly `list` contains 5 elements. With the `foreach` loop, you copy them to `items`. So this `List<DataItem>` also contains 5 elements. Then you call `callback(items.ToArray(), null)` (is that what you mean by "_leaves the function_"?) and after that callback returns `list` is empty, or `items` is empty? That's hard to believe from the code shown here. Something must happen in the code you did not show us. Also set a breakpoint in the callback where you assign `_items = item.ToList()` and check the content of `item` and `_items` before and after.

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you for the help. It is working sort of. If I remove the async calls, it works but it does not work if I try to make it async.

Comment: of course, making it synchronous changes the behaviour, ie the constructor of MainViewModel does not return until data is ready. In the async case, it returns immedately. So we don't know what happens in the meantime, until the callback is executed. Or how often the MainViewModel constructor is called, ... And to be honest, I'm absolutely not deap enough into MVVM to give an answer to these questions.